# How many days should I fill in for a double-entry Schengen visa application?

Tags: visas, schengen, applications, latvia

I will be staying in Latvia for 26 days and I want to apply for a double-entry visa. On the application form, should I write 26 days or 90 days?

From comment:

> My first entry is on 1st September and I'm staying for 17 days. While the second entry is on December 20th and I will be staying 10 days. That's what makes the total number of 26 days. Are you advising me to apply for only 17 days based on my first visit??

Comment: Thanks for your reply. My first entry is on 1st september and im staying for 17 days. While the second entry is on december 20th and i will be staying 10 days. Thats what makes the total number of 26 days. Are you advicing me to apply for only 17 days? Based on my first visit??

Comment: Please also advice me please, myproof of strong ties is my intention to continue my law education which statts in novemeber although im currently learning database manangement at a computer institute. And i am providiing a receipt to show enrollment as well as an objection letter from the computer school. I am also showing my graduation statement of result and admission letter to the university as i cannot proof im awaiting admission in any other way. Does this suffice

Comment: How do you come up with 90 days?

Comment: How do you get 17+10 to be 26?

Comment: Be careful.  It's easy to miscount days.  By the Schengen counting rules, staying for 17 days with arrival on 1 September means that you will leave on 17 September.  Arriving on 20 December and staying for 10 days means that you will leave on 29 December.  As implied by @HenningMakholm, the sum of 17 and 10 is *27,* not 26.  However, if your departure dates are not 17 September and 29 December then you must adjust the total accordingly.  But since it's now 11 September, perhaps you can post an answer or comment to tell us what happened.

Answer (score 1):

> My first entry is on 1st September and I'm staying for 17 days. While the second entry is on December 20th and I will be staying 10 days. That's what makes the total number of 26 days. Are you advising me to apply for only 17 days based on my first visit?

You are planning two trips to Latvia and, if the itinerary you included in your visa application outlines both trips (entry and exit dates), you would give the total number of days (27, by my count).

Comment: The asker of the question did not give exit dates, so we don't actually know whether the 17-day and 10-day durations of the two visits have been calculated correctly.  Given the asker's assertion that the sum of those numbers is 26, I am skeptical.